# How to write gherkin scenario directly on Xray test case creation page

Tags: testing, bdd, gherkin, scenarios, jira-xray

How do I get the below options like test details (to add BDD scenario) when creating test cases?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7L5r.png)

On my one it just looks like this. I have imported the 6 test type from Xray into my JIRA project. Is there more configuration that needs to be done? Once created, I can click on the test case and insert the scenario there, but surely I should be able to do this whilst creating in the first place. I can't find anything on this new layout online.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcMGd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Xray on Jira server/Data Center, then you can fill out the Cucumber Scenario details right away as mentioned [here](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62268093#Gherkin(BDDTests)-UsingtheIssuedialog).
If you're using Jira Cloud then you can't do this due to current limitations on Jira/Atlassian side; in this case, you have to create the Test first and then edit the scenario/scenario outline from the Test issue screen.